# Average of Dynamic Range Excel ex.monthly average

Tags: excel, average, offset

The following video starting at 6:04 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDKhXl7GLOM  solves the problem of dynamic range.
 
I understand that it has to be minus 1- because it has to minus a row and multiply by 3 if it's 1*3-> the first range will start from 3, which is where the second range should start. However, I can't understand why: 
 
1. do we put parenthesis in  front of rows i.e =(rows($J$5:J5)-1)*3+1 and not =rows(($J$5:J5)-1)*3+1.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In excel, the function rows of every constant is 1, i.e =rows(5)=1 
Subsequently,  `=rows(($J$5:J5)+1)` reads rows(2) =1 or `=rows(($J$5:J5)-5)` =1.
When `=(rows($J$5:J5)+1)` excel reads the function rows + 1 which is 2.